# Spring Boot Validation with environment variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I would like to put the value of a spring boot environment variable into a validation annotation (@Min, @Max), but i don't know how to do it. Here is my code :

```
public class MessageDTO {

@Value("${validationMinMax.min}")
private Integer min;

@JsonProperty("Message_ID")
@NotBlank(message = "messageId cannot be blank.")
@Pattern(regexp = "\\w+", message = "messageId don't suits the pattern")
private String messageId;

@JsonProperty("Message_Type")
@NotBlank(message = "messageType cannot be blank")
private String messageType;

@JsonProperty("EO_ID")
@NotBlank(message = "eoId cannot be blank")
private String eoId;

@JsonProperty("UI_Type")
@NotNull(message = "uiType cannot be null")
@Min(1)
@Max(3)
private Integer uiType;
```

And here is my application.yml :

```
server:
  port: 8080 
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: message_keyspace
      port: 9042
      contact-points:
        - localhost

validationMinMax:
  min: 1
  max: 3
```

I would like to put the field "min" and "max" of my yml into the annotation field @Min() and @Max() of my attribute uiType. Does anyone knows how to do it ? Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: There is a simple answer, you cannot. Annotations are static metadata and as such cannot be injected. The support that exists for some annotations comes from the fact that when reading the annotations the expressions are evaluated. However that is only possible for spring managed annotations as these aren't such a thing such support isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own validation annotation with a custom validator. In this validator you can autowire spring beans and inject configuration properties:

```java
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { MyValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface MyValidationAnnotation {
    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends javax.validation.Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

The validator class:

```java
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidationAnnotation, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    public void initialize(MyValidationAnnotation constraintAnnotation) {
      // ...
    }

    public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      if(service.validate(value)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

}
```

And then use it:

```java
@MyValidationAnnotation
Integer foo;
```